# Monthly Celery Beat task also runs after celery restart

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I have a task that is set to run on the first day of every month at 05:00 using celery beat. It has been set as follows in settings.py:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'generate_monthly_reports': {
            'task': 'api.tasks_reports.generate_monthly_reports',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=5, day_of_month=1)
        },
    }
```

This works well and runs reliably. However, I have recently discovered that it is also run whenever Celery is restarted, e.g. when a server code update is made and celery restarted via supervisor. I am using Celery 5.2.6, Python 3.8 and Django 4.0.4.

How can I prevent this task running when Celery is restarted please?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem do you have a solution?

Comment: @Dante for now I have just added code to the "generate_monthly_reports" method to check whether it is the 1st of the month before running. I believe there may be a solution added in Celery 5.3.0, but have not tested it - https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#beat-cron-starting-deadline